# mongoose .create give node.js "ValidationError: validation failed: Cast to [undefined] failed for value..."

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, mongoose

I have an App and I want to push a comment to a single id page (showing a campground) passing a value in an array. I use to express and mongoose.

Error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1):
>   ValidationError: validation failed: Cast to [undefined] failed for
>   value...

This is the model of the page to show:

**models/campground.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
```

The campgroundSchema refers to the Comment model:

**models/comment.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

Both are used in the Create comment route, that find a campground by id, then create a comment retrieving data from a form, the trying to push that comment into the comments array of the previously founded campground, and save:

**app.js**

```
app.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments", function (req, res) {
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function (err, campground) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        } else {
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function (err, comment) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    campground.comments.push(comment);
                    campground.save();
                    res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
                    console.log(req.body.comment);
                    }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

This is the code of the "add new comment" form:

**comments/new.ejs**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Add a new Comment to <%= campground.name %></h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin:25px auto;">
            <form action="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/comments" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment[text]" placeholder="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="comment[author]" placeholder="author">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the "show campground" page:

**campgrounds/show.ejs**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <h1><%= campground.name %></h1>
            <div class="...">
                <img src="<%= campground.image %>" class="media-object">
                <p><%= campground.description %></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/comments/new">Add New Comment</a></p>
                <% campground.comments.forEach(function(comment) {%>
                    <p><strong><%= comment.text %></strong> - <%= comment.author %></p>
                <% })%>
                <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The route redirect correctly to the "show campground" page, but no new comment is added to the loop. I have a Node Warning in console:

```
(node:1940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): 
ValidationError: Campground validation failed: comments: Cast to [undefined] failed for value 
"[{
"_id":"5a55f5afd9bf5c0794ca7220",
"text":"previously existing comment",
"author":"first author",
"__v":0
}]" 
at path "comments"
```

Please note that the comment logged is the existing comment, the new one submitted by the form is only logged because of `console.log(req.body.comment)` an example:

```
{ text: 'lortem ipsum', author: 'nick beer' }
```

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**: thanks to JavaEvgen, I try nested schema and the app works without changing other lines. But seems I cannot work with referenced schemas. Where is the Error?

Comment: try to pass your "campground" as a third argument to Comment.create function. I think it's just undefined there

Comment: campground is passed by `Campground.findById()`. if i `console.log(campground);`  i have the campground logged with the new comment, but without the first comment. Every time I add a comment is the same, logged in console the new comment (only one), but showed the old one

Comment: it's not `campground.comments.push(comment);` but `Campground.comments.push(comment._id);`

Comment: I try your code but not work because of Error: `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. `Campground` is the model name for a particular `campground` I want to update. `comment` is the object to push into the array, I do not want to push the  `_id` but all the fields of the object into the  `campground.comments` array

Comment: Another solution would be not to use a separate schema for comments. You can use "nested" schema. It would be much easier this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use nested schema to hold both your campgound and comments like so:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var comment = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  author: String
});

var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  image: String,
  description: String,
  comments: [comment]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
```

In this approach you save your comments like this:

```
Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, campground) {
  if (err) throw err;
    campground.comments.push(req.body.comment);
      campgound.save(function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
            res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
    });
});
```

Or you can also try to avoid using .create function of Mongoose and use .save instead to create you comments like this:

```
var comment = new Comment(req.body.comment);
comment.save(your_callback_here);
```

And as addition to that, I have checked my own solution when I used the approach you tried at first and I noticed couple of small differences.

First is that I also had a backward reference from Comment schema to in my case Movie, so I think You could try to add it as well into your Comment schema like this:

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: String,
    campground: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Campground' }
});
```

And after this I think you have to save your comment first so it would get an _id from mongoDB and only after that you can push this id to the campground object. And you actually do it in right order by using .create, but since nothing works I think you could try something like this:

```
var comment = new Comment(req.body);
comment.campground = req.campground._id;

comment.save(function(err, comment){
    if(err) return next(err);

    comment.campground.comments.push(comment);
    comment.campground.save(function(err, campground){
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Using nested code works, I'm very curious to know how to configure references in mongoose models to push only the Id and not the entire sub-array

Comment: I'm happy to hear that it work. It would also be great if you mark my answer as the correct one if it worked for you. And for more info regarding your problem you can read an official documentation of mongoose [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). I'm pretty sure you missed something very small, because in my opinion your code looked right

Comment: Thanks, I will try some code and maybe open a new Question about mongoose reference vs embed schema.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I find with the use of reference ObjectId is the code below:

```
app.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments", function (req, res) {
    Comment.create(req.body.comment, function (err, comment) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            Campground.findOne({"_id": req.params.id})
            .populate("comments")
            .exec(function (err, campground) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect("/campgrounds");
                } else {
                    campground.comments.push(comment);
                    campground.save();
                    res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
                    // console.log(req.body.comment);
                    // console.log(campground.comments);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

we even need to push comment id to to campground.

Change this route to shown below:

```
app.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments", function (req, res) {
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function (err, campground) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        } else {
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function (err, comment) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    campground.comments.push(comment);
                    campground.save();
                    res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
                    console.log(req.body.comment);
                    }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

to this route

```
app.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments", function(req,res){
   Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, campground) {
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment){
              if(err){
                  console.log(err);
              } else {
                    campground.comments.push(comment);
                    campground.save();
                    campground.comments.push(comment._id);
                    campground.save();
                    res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
              }
           });
       }
   });
});
```